# If we could get a file's binary form, would this method of file compression work?

Tags: compression

I'm not quite sure how easy it is to fetch the binary composition of a file, but suppose we have some file with this representation:

010011

We could make 2 arrays.

One which stores the position of the 0s:
['x', '', 'x', 'x', '', '']

And another which stores the position of the 1s (which is simply the opposite of the previous array):
['', 'x', '', '', 'x', 'x']

Then we can persist these two arrays into a file, and voila?

I don't know, is there something i'm not realizing?

I'm not an expert in compression, was just wondering if this would work.

Comment: How much space would it take up to store the position of each of the 0's and 1's?

Comment: Yeah it depends on the language i guess, for instance a boolean in an array takes one byte in some langauges. I suppose the idea could work if instead of marking each location we entered the starting and ending locations for a particular set of repeating 0s and 1s. I Don't know i guess it was a bad idea hehe

Comment: Your two areas take more space than the original.  Thus, it is not "compression".

Comment: @zeroRooter see [Huffman Encoding](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

Comment: See also [BWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BWT), [MTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Move-to-front_transform) and then [RLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). Also, why would it be difficult to "get a file's binary form"?

Comment: Also read [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), which is a tool that can help find loopholes in one's arguments about a compression scheme.

Comment: if anything this is more of a parity/error detecting code (though not a very good one) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_code

Comment: A binary file is a file that stores the position of the 1's and of the 0's ............sequentially.

Answer (score 7):

The most compact possible representation of your arrays would be 1 bit per entry. You have two arrays, each of length 6. I.e. your compressed file is 6+6 bits long, while your original file is 6 bits long. This is an *increase* of 100%.

Also, as @jk pointed out in his comment: your second array is identical to your input data. The first array is identical to the inverse of your input data.

```
       010011  # original
101100 010011  # 'compressed'
```

So, not only is your compressed data twice as long, it also contains an exact copy of the original data.

Comment: additionally one of the arrays is the original file while the other is the complement of the original file